# Mouse pointer moves jerkily on exernal display

Tags: display, mouse

From time to time, my mouse pointer starts to move jerkily or erratically while I move it around.

The effect is very visible and distracting. I've captured [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VUo4VlveKQw) at 0.25× speed of my screen (<kbd>.</kbd> and <kbd>,</kbd> are handy here to step single frames in the YouTube video player).

This starts and stops without an apparent pattern to me. Sometimes it lasts for a few minutes, sometimes for a few hours. Then it might start again after a few minutes or a few hours. Things I've figured out and that I'm pretty certain about:

- The effect, when it happens, is only visible on my external display (a DELL P2418D). When I move the pointer to the internal display, the pointer moves flawlessly, then, when I move it back to the external display, it moves jerkily again.
- It's not my input device. It happens whether I use my external corded mouse or the internal trackpad. It persists if I unplug my external mouse and only use the internal trackpad. It happens whether the mouse is plugged in via the external display's USB port or via the Apple USB-C adapter plugged into my Mac. No Bluetooth input devices are connected to the Mac.
- The video signal is not messed up by the external display (e.g. by reordering frames). When I drag something (e.g. a window or an element in a graphics editor), only the mouse pointer moves jerkily, not the thing that is grabbed. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yGQnQSOKsUo) shows that effect.
- Unplugging and re-plugging the external display at the USB-C port on my MacBook fixes the problem for a short time. The pointer moves flawlessly after plugging in the external monitor. But the problem can re-appear even after just a minute.

Some things I checked that could have been the culprit:

- All apps under *Allow the apps below to control your computer* in System Preferences *Security & Privacy* are unchecked.
- The Mac is plugged into a 61 W USB-C power supply (according to *System information*).
- The CPU is mostly idle (> 75 % idle) most of the time, even when the problem occurs.
- Rebooting does not fix the problem. The issue might re-appear after few minutes after rebooting.
- The problem appears on 2 separate user accounts.
- The problem appears regardless of which application is in the front and persists no matter what application I switch or launch.

I'm at a loss on what to try next to fix this issue.

---

#### Summary of my hard- and software

Mac: MacBook Pro (14-inch, 2021) (MacBookPro18,3) 
OS: macOS 12.6.8 
External display: DELL P2418D connected via a "USB-C Digital AV Multiport Adapter" from Apple

*Displays/Graphics* and *USB* categories from *System Information*:

[image: Displays/Graphics]
[image: USB]